# Bitcoind JSON-RPC Calls Not Working

Tags: php, json, bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm trying to use the [Bitcoind JSON-RPC API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29) from PHP to control my wallet using the following code.

```
<?php 
  echo "hello";

  require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php';

  $bitcoin = new jsonRPCClient('http://bitcoinrpc:password@127.0.0.1:8332/');

  echo "Received: ".$bitcoin->getnewaddress()."\n";

?>
```

Which just prints out `hello` and not even `Recieved:`. You can view it [here.](http://bitcoinpublish.com/fred.php)

My bitcoin.conf:

```
rpcuser=bitcoinrpc
rpcpassword=password
alertnotify=echo %s | mail -s "Bitcoin Alert" admin@foo.com
server=1
```

What is happening exactly and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? It looks like your script aborts somewhere in the included `jsonRPCClient.php` file or because it is not found by PHP.

Comment: @Lukas I was trying to use the [JSON-RPC PHP Library](http://jsonrpcphp.org/?page=index&lang=en) but didn't have it "installed". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to install the [JSON-RPC PHP Library.](http://jsonrpcphp.org/?page=index&lang=en) Once installed it worked beautifully.

**Please everyone, as a public service announcement I ask all y'all to remember to install your libraries.**